# Notation for linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find all eigenvectors and eigenvalues of

$T: P_2(C) → P_2(C), p(x) ↦ (x^2 + 2ix + 1)p′′(x) + ip(1)$.

What, precisely, does $p(1)$ in the last term mean? I assume it just means $1$, but if so, why not just write 1? Or else, is it the polynomial 1? Or does it refer to the 1 in the standard basis $\beta = \{ 1,x,x^2 \}$? But in that case, what if there's another basis that looks differently?

(Surely, it is correct that $\beta = \{ 1,x,x^2 \}$ is indeed a basis for this transformation?)

Comment: I assume $P_2(\mathbb C)$ means "polynomials of degree $≤2$ with complex coefficients", right?  So then $p(1)$ is the polynomial evaluated at $1$.

Comment: But there's no polynomial to evaluate..

Comment: @Bronze Yes, there is: $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @KBS Ok, but in that case isn't the polynomial recursive? There will be an endless number of $p(1)$..

Comment: I don't understand. You pick a vector $p(x)$ and then you see what T does to it. That's how you define a linear map.

Comment: Just work examples. What is $Tx$, say?  What is $Tx^2$?

Comment: Small detail about the final parenthetical: the transformation $T$ doesn't have have a basis. The vector space $P_2(C)$ has many bases (of which $\beta = \{ 1, x, x^2 \}$ is one).

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear (in addition to being slow). I mean, how can I evaluate $p(1)$, when $p(1)$ is itself in the definition of the linear map? Or are you saying that only the part $(x^2+2ix+1)p''(x)$ is the polynomial, so that $p(1)=1^2+2i+1=2+2i$?

Comment: No, $T$ is a function that takes a polynomial $p(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$ as input and spits another polynomial out as output. For example, if $p(x) = x^2 + 1$, then $p''(x) = 2$ and $p(1) = 2$, so $T(p) = 2(x^2 + 2 i x + 1) + 2i$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $p(1)$ just means 'evaluation of $p$ at $1$', so, for instance, if $p(x) = x^2 + 1$, then $p(1) = 1^2 + 1 = 2$ and $T(p(x)) = (x^2 + 2ix + 1) \cdot 2 + i \cdot 2 = 2x^2 + 4ix + 2i + 2$.

Answer (score -2):

The operator $T$ can be represented in terms of the following matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0\\4i & 0 & 0\\2+i & i & i\end{bmatrix},$$

where we have used the fact that $p(x)=p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0$ and the natural basis $\{x^2,x,1\}$. Therefore, $p''(x)=2p_2$ and $p(1)=p_2+p_1+p_0$. Indeed, we have that

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0\\4i & 0 & 0\\2+i & i & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p_2\\p_1\\p_0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2p_2\\4ip_2\\(2+i)p_2+p_1+p_0\end{bmatrix},$$

where we can verify that the right hand side is exactly $$T(p(x))=(x^2 + 2ix + 1)p′′(x) + ip(1)=2p_2x^2+4ip_2x+((2+i)p_2+p_1+p_0).$$

Clearly, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_2=2$, and $\lambda_3=i$.  Moreover,

- the eigenvector associated with the 0 eigenvalue is given by

$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},$$
which corresponds to the polynomial $p_1(x)=x-1$, meaning that $T(p_1(x))=0$,

- the eigenvector associated with the 2 eigenvalue is given by

$$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}-(1+2i)\\2(2-i)\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
which corresponds to the polynomial $p_2(x)=-(1+2i)x^2+2(2-i)x+1$, meaning that $T(p_2(x))=2p_2(x)$,

- the eigenvector associated with the $i$ eigenvalue is given by

$$v_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},$$
which corresponds to the polynomial $p_3(x)=1$, meaning that $T(p_3(x))=ip_3(x)$,

Comment: Although this answers the question that was posed to the OP, this answer does not actually answer the question that the OP wants answered.

Comment: @Magdiragdag This question has been replied multiple times in the comments. If you also read more carefully, you will see that I am giving the exact expression for $p(1)$ in the basis I am considering in my answer. In this regard, I am providing an answer to that question as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Oddly enough I almost got the same results, though I missed an eigenvalue. But here is the strange part: I interpreted $p=1$ as equaling $1$, and I still got exactly the same matrix $A$ as you, even though I apparently did it wrong. And I still don't get how the evaluation works. :I

Comment: @Bronze What do you mean by "still don't get how the evaluation works"?

Comment: Well, If look at the answer above yours, $p(x)=4ix+2i+2$, but from your Matrix $A$ it looks like $p(x)=i$. I just don't see how to calculate $Tp(1)$, $Tp(x)$, and $Tp(x^2)$.

Comment: No, the other answer is saying that $T(x^2 + 1) = 2x^2 + 4 i x + 2i + 2$. There is a fundamental mixup here regarding $T$ and $p$; for most polynomials $p$, $T(p(x^2))$ is not even defined, since $p(x^2)$ is of degree greater than $2$ if $p$ is a degree $2$ polynomial, but $T$ only accepts vectors of degree less than or equal to 2 as inputs.

Comment: @Bronze No, it is clearly said in my answer that $p(x)=p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0$ and that $T(p(x))=2p_2x^2+4ip_2x+((2+i)p_2+p_1+p_0)$. The domain of the operator is the set of polynomials of at most order 2.